# how to use an in clause to check if a column is a certain string or not when referencing 3 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this SQL statement and it joining 2 tables...

```
SELECT TRIDENT.Maintenance.RCFAs.*, TRIDENT.Maintenance.Equipment.EquipmentName
FROM TRIDENT.Maintenance.RCFAs
LEFT JOIN TRIDENT.Maintenance.Equipment 
ON TRIDENT.Maintenance.Equipment.EquipmentId = TRIDENT.Maintenance.RCFAs.EquipmentId
WHERE 1 = 1
```

Now I have to reference a third table because I have a dropdown by the name of `components` that we will use to lookup stuff on the table named `TRIDENT.Maintenance.RCFAXrefComponents`. So if "bolts" is selected from the dropdown it will look up the YEAR and RCFAID which makes a unqiue key for both `RCFAXrefComponents` and `RCFAs` and checks if there are any rows in `RCFAs` that had "bolts" in the `component` column when looking up that YEAR and RCFAId. A coworker suggested I use an IN clause to check if the YEAR and RCFAId is in that `RCFAXrefComponents`. He said it might be tricky, but I'm a little lost on how to do this.

Below is the `RCFAs` table that I want to grab the YEAR and RCFAId values together and lookup on the other to see if that bolt is also there. Then it should bring up the line item on `RCFAs` table to output to user 
[image]

this is RCFAXrefComponents table below
[image]

```
 Public Shared Function GetRCFAList(rcfaNumber As Integer?, description As String,
               failureType As String, equipmentDescription As String, componentSelection As String) As List(Of RCFA)
        Dim sql = "SELECT r.*, e.EquipmentName FROM TRIDENT.Maintenance.RCFAs AS r LEFT JOIN TRIDENT.Maintenance.Equipment AS e ON e.EquipmentId = r.EquipmentId JOIN TRIDENT. Maintenance.RCFAXrefComponents AS c ON c.Year = r.Year AND c.RCFAId = r.RCFAId WHERE"

        If failureType <> "" Then
            sql += " AND RCFAs.FailureType = '" & failureType.ToUpper & "'"
        End If
        If description <> "" Then
            sql += " AND RCFAs.ShortDesc LIKE '%" & description.ToUpper & "%'"
        End If
        If equipmentDescription <> "" Then
            sql += " AND Equipment.EquipmentName LIKE '%" & equipmentDescription.ToUpper & "%'"
        End If
        If componentSelection <> "" Then
            sql += " c.ComponentId = '%" & componentSelection.ToUpper & "%'"
        End If

        Dim dbConn As New Trident.Core.DBConnection
        Dim ds = dbConn.FillDataSet(sql)
        Dim tmpList As New List(Of RCFA)

        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows

            tmpList.Add(New RCFA(New Trident.Objects.Maintenance.RCFA.RCFA(dr)))
        Next
        Return tmpList
    End Function
```

Comment: Don't paste screenshots of your schema and data. Type it in.

Comment: oh ok thought this would be easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a simple `JOIN` with the `RFCAXrefComponents` table, and a `WHERE` clause that filters the component ID.

```
SELECT r.*, e.EquipmentName
FROM TRIDENT.Maintenance.RCFAs AS r
LEFT JOIN TRIDENT.Maintenance.Equipment AS e
    ON e.EquipmentId = r.EquipmentId
JOIN TRIDENT.Maintenance.RCFAXrefComponents AS c
    ON c.Year = r.Year
    AND c.RCFAId = r.RCFAId
WHERE c.ComponentID = 'BOLTS'
```

Comment: tried to implement this in code i edited my post at the bottom with my revise code but pulls zero records. each selection box if they chose to use that as a parameter  tacks on a search parameter to the statement. component selection is the last one im trying to fix

Comment: You may have a syntax error in your SQL. If one of the first 3 search fields is filled in, the SQL will say `WHERE AND`. Try ending the initial SQL with `WHERE 1=1`. Then you can add `AND <other condition>` to it safely.

Comment: i tried to paste the sql statement into Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and that didnmt yield any records either but there are 4 with bolts

Comment: Can you make a sqlfiddle with the sample data and the query you used?

Comment: got this to work BOLTS was singular in the DB and it pulled right up

Answer (score 0):

I may be confused but it sounds like you need to use EXISTS.

```
SELECT  r.*,
        e.EquipmentName
FROM    TRIDENT.Maintenance.RCFAs r
        LEFT JOIN TRIDENT.Maintenance.Equipment e ON e.EquipmentId = r.EquipmentId
WHERE   EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM   TRIDENT.Maintenance.RCFAXrefComponents c
                 WHERE  c.Year = r.Year
                        AND c.RCFAId = r.RCFAId
                        AND c.ComponentId LIKE '%BOLTS%' )
```

you may not need the `c.ComponentId LIKE '%BOLTS%'`  you might just want `c.ComponentId = 'BOLTS'`

Comment: oh ok if i wanted to grab all line items in the RCFA that has bolts in the RCFAXref so that it will pull in data like in the updated screen shot about i should just replace SELECT 1 in the nested statement to SELECT *    right?

Comment: Select 1 and Select * would get you the same result.. EXISTS just looks for any result found.

Comment: tried to implement this in code i edited my post at the bottom with my revise code but pulls zero records. each selection box if they chose to use that as a parameter  tacks on a search parameter to the statement. component selection is the last one im trying to fix